# Use an image for coloring a `plotly` surface plot

Tags: plotly, surface

I have a 3D image from a microscope as well as a corresponding light microsccope image. I would like to show the 3D image as a surface using `plotly`. However, instead of using some color scale I would like to make the color of each pixel have a color independent of the z-value and overlay the light microscope image. My idea was to use the `surfacecolor` argument as it is stated in the documentation:

> Sets the surface color values, used for setting a color scale independent of `z`.

```py
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Surface(z=surface_data, surfacecolor=surface_color))
fig.show()
```

Here, `surface_data` is `numpy` array with the shape (206, 247) (the 3D surface) and `surface_color` is a `numpy` array with the shape (206, 247, 3). The second array corresponds to the RGB values for each pixel from the image that I would like to use. However, as I have learned this does not change the actual color but only changes the value for determining the color from the scale.

Does anybody have an idea how I can accomplish that?

**Update:** I also tried to supply the `colorscale` argument with a color scale like this:

```
[[0.0, 'rgb(88,90,105)'],
 [2e-05, 'rgb(112,110,123)'],
 [4e-05, 'rgb(123,114,133)'],
 [6e-05, 'rgb(141,134,141)'],
 [8e-05, 'rgb(169,165,156)'],
 [0.0001, 'rgb(185,177,175)'],
 [0.00012, 'rgb(195,192,185)'],
 [0.00014, 'rgb(196,190,192)'],
...
```

where I added the `surfacecolor` with a 2D array with the image dimensions with values corresponding to the first values of each entry in the color scale, i.e.

```
array([[0.0000e+00, 2.0000e-05, 4.0000e-05, ..., 4.8000e-03, 4.8200e-03,
        4.8300e-03],
       [4.8500e-03, 4.8700e-03, 4.8900e-03, ..., 9.6500e-03, 9.6700e-03,
        9.6900e-03],
       [9.7100e-03, 9.7300e-03, 9.7500e-03, ..., 1.4500e-02, 1.4520e-02,
        1.4540e-02],
       ...,
```

But still I only get a binary color scale.